# if $X_t^2-t$ is a martingale then how $X_t$ is a Brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, martingales, stochastic-analysis

How do we show that if $X_t$ and $X_t^2 -t$ is martingale then $X_t$ is Brownian motion.

Comment: Have a look at Levy's theorem